# Как в MVC добавить поле из связанной таблицы на представление по id?

Tags: mvc

Есть две связанные таблицы. Как получить поле из одной связанной таблицы в представлении другой по ID
1) ID_B | ID_A | DATE| Число возвращённых
2) ID_A| Name | Число взятых

Как в представлении получить поля
 Name | Число взятых |Число возвращённых

Answer (score 2):

[здесь на VB](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/235/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller), [здесь на C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) примеры , там же можно скачать учебные проекты . [Руководство на русском от Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/)

После уточнения вопроса , ещё раз обратимся по ссылкам, данным для примера выше  , там увидим , что на основании вашеи модели , данные которой вам нужно вывести на страницу , функция контроллера обрабатывает ваши данные , как пример - берет все данные, что есть в модели

```
    Function Index() As ActionResult 
    Return View(db.**ВашаМодель**.ToList())
   End Function
```

и передает данные для их отображения на страницу , сделать это можно реализацией по предлагаемым вам программой шаблонам , или самостоятельно .

в итоге страница будет сформирована с данными , примерно следующим образом

```
    <table class="table"> 
//строка заголовки таблицы , с колонками по имени своиства
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ЧислоВзятых)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.ЧислоВозвращенных)
        </th>

        <th></th> // колонка для выравнивания таблицы при размешении ссылок на методы деиствии с выбранными ID в контроллере
    </tr>

@For Each item In Model
//строка с данными для выбранных значении (заголовков)  - по колонкам, формируется для каждого ID вашеи модели 
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.ЧислоВзятых)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.ЧислоВозвращенных)
        </td>
        //ссылки , сформированные реизером на методы действия контроллера,  с указанием id выбранной пользователем сущности и именем метода 
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Править", "Edit", New With {.id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Детали", "Details", New With {.id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "Delete", New With {.id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
Next

</table>
```

проще всего скачать учебные проекты , почитать их для изучения ,  посмотреть - что в приложении на странице написано и что отображается на этой странице в браузере , и тогда немного будет понятно , что и как формируется , сам сеичас примерно этим и занят ...

вот [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) и [здесь](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/241/mvc-5-with-ef-6-in-visual-basic-creating-an-entity-framework-data-model) ещё более полные по моделям и функционалу учебные проекты "Университет Контосо"
Далее , в зависимости от версии Студии - 15 или выше , при создании контроллера программа уже сама создаст наиболее часто используемые методы действий с Моделями Данных и страницы с кодом для возможности реализации этих методов , можно в принципе все посмотреть там и понять , как и что и куда отправляется и редактируется в последствии на странице и передается обратно в контроллер для обработки ... Для этого при создании контроллера выберите контроллер с представлениями , использующий энтити фрэмворк .
Вот ещё , [тут можно](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/codeeditor?cid=mvc-Dioxf9) попробовать самому помудрить ...